# Vue Router does not redirect to the right page

Tags: vue.js

When I try to push a new **profile** with an **profileID** with **VueRouter** I get an error saying: ***Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/user/ID".*** When clicking on the button it is not redirecting me to another page, it just jumps to the beginning of the current page.

I declared my **routes** in my **index.js** file like this:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'EntryPoint',
        component: EntryPoint
    },
    {
        path: '/main',
        name: 'Main',
        component: Main
    },
    {
        path: '/user/:id',
        name: 'User Current',
        component: CurrentUser
    },
```

When I am on an **user** page the path in the url already contains an **userID** - so f.e. ***#/user/1111***.

Now on the same user page I want to navigate to another user when the user clicks on a button:

```
 <ContactCard
          v-for="user in users"
          @goToUser="goToUser(user.id)"
        />

goToUser(userId) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "User Current", params: { id: userId } });
    },
```

The **id** which I get from my **users** array contains different id´s for each user.

Any suggestions why the routing is not working properly?

When clicking on the button I see for an instance that the url is changing with the right path: ***#/user/1112***. Inseatd of updating the page it removes the url, jumps to top and gives me the error message from above when selecting the button again.

When I log

```
console.log(this.$route.path);
```

on button click I get the correct route - **/user/ID** but it is not updating anything.

---

UPDATE:

As Zdravko Pernikov suggested I keyed my  and it works:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="nav">
            <label>Welcome</label>

            <router-link to="/main">Welcome</router-link>

            <router-link to="/User">User</router-link>

        </div>
        <router-view :key="$route.path"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your param name is `id`, not `userId`. Try `params: { id: userId }`

Comment: Wrong typo. Fixed it. My param was **id**

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that you're missing a key attribute in your for loop. Try adding one and tell us what happens. `v-for="(user,i) in users" :key="i"`

Comment: The error message warns you that you are navigating to `/profile/:id` - but your route is actually `/user/:id` Have you checked that you do not navigate to `/profile` route ?

Comment: @ZdravkoPernikov nothing changed.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I am on the correct route. I logged it in the console on button click

Comment: What button do you click on from the user page? Can you post that code and also the code where you have the router-view?

Comment: well, it may happen also because you are reusing your `CurrentUser` component and not listen for changes since it's already rendered.. can you try keying your global router view `<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
` and tell us again what happens

Comment: glad I could help, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happen because you are reusing your `CurrentUser` component and you are not listening for changes since it's already rendered.
You can try keying your global router view `<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>` your components will be rerendered on different routes.

Comment: Note that keying your global router-view is not a good practise and can lead to performance issues. You should instead use watchers in the view-level components to know when route params change and handle those scenarios on a per-route level.

Comment: Yes, I don't remember anymore why I suggested keying it, but most definitely what you are suggesting is the better and cleaner option.